# Can anyone help me graph an Ordinary Differential equation?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, graphing-functions

*Given a Cauchy problem* $y'(x)= \frac{x^2y^3}{1+y^2}$ *with initial conditions* $y(x_0) = y_0$? *I know that the $y=0$ *is one solution of the given problem* and function is increasing or decreasing for* $y_0>0$ *and* $y_0<0$ *respectively for all* $x>0$ *and we cannot cross the $y≡0$ because doing so would contradict the uniqueness property of the problem*. *But I can't understand how to graph when $x<0$*. *Also, how can I apply monotonicity and asymptotic theorem when*$x\rightarrow-∞$? *Is it possible to graph without taking a second derivative?*

Comment: You could just make a stream plot (eg. `StreamPlot[ {1+y^2,x^2*y^2},{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3}]` on [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=StreamPlot%5B+%7B1%2By%5E2%2Cx%5E2*y%5E2%7D%2C%7Bx%2C-3%2C3%7D%2C%7By%2C-3%2C3%7D%5D)), there isn't any special for $x < 0$. The behavior of $y(x)$ for $x < 0$ is essentially the same as that of $-y(-x)$.

Comment: Use this applet to get the graph of the vector field for this eq. [link](https://www.geogebra.org/m/W7dAdgqc)

Comment: @achille hui But the idea is to make a freehand graph without relying on any external sources. The graph has to be drawn purely based on observation(not even the slope-field method). You're right that the behavior of y(x) for x<0 is essentially the same as that of −y(−x) but why does y'(x) move towards the solution (y=0) when x tends to infinity?